# Refresh svg coordinates on window resize

Tags: javascript, svg, resize, coordinates

I'm new to SVG and I'm having trouble solving this problem :

I'm trying to create a system of points, rotating around a single axis, like a solar system.
The center point is a round div, placed to the center of the viewport with the help of the CSS calc function :

```
left:  calc(50% - myDivWidth/2);
top: calc(50% - myDivHeight/2);
```

I placed SVG circles around this central point with the "cx" and "cy" attributes and everything works fine.

Here's the problem : when I resize the window, the div is automatically moved to stay at the center of the screen. But my SVG circles are not moving because the coordinate system doesn't stretch to the new size of the viewport. Now if I reload the page after resizing, everything is placed correctly again.

I thought I could recalculate the coordinates of my circles when a resize occurs but isn't it a bit heavy ?
All my circles are placed in a svg tag with a 100% height and width.

I hope you can help me with this ! Thanks !

Comment: Would you be able to place your code in a jsfiddle so we can take a better look at it?

Comment: Of course ! Here it is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7y238Lf/)
The code is a bit messy for the moment, it will be cleaned. But if you have some suggestions about how I could handle this better I'm also listening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `viewBox` attribute to your SVG, it will automatically be scaled to fit it's parent viewport (`<div class="univers">`).

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-315 -315 630 630">
```

With this viewBox you can use (0,0) as the origin for your orbiting circles.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/n7y238Lf/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! How do you define the values to put in the viewBox ? It seems to be working in the jsfiddle but in my local code it breaks everything.

Comment: Well your largest circle radii was 300.  So I added some padding to make it 315.  Then in order to have the centre at (0,0), I went from -315 to +315.  The viewBox is specified as "minX minY width height", so the final viewBox is "-315 -315 630 630".

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Now that you said it, it makes perfect sense. Thanks again, you made my day !